# Fetching from table throught its own data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have got this kind of table

```
| SessionId | Action |
----------------------
| 1         | LOGIN  |
| 1         | INDEX  |
| 3         | LOGIN  |
| 1         | SHOW   |
| 3         | DELETE |
| 1         | INSERT |
| 6         | LOGIN  |
| 3         | LOGOUT |
| 5         | LOGIN  |
```

I need to fetch count of all actions without `LOGIN` for each `SessionId` which has got `LOGIN` action.

```
| SessionId | count |
---------------------
| 1         | 3     |
| 3         | 2     |
| 5         | 0     |
| 6         | 0     |
```

And I am using sql server now (Mysql syntax will be ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added LEFT JOIN so that SessionId values 5 and 6 are included in the results. This also has the benefit of eliminating the subquery.

```
SELECT t.SessionId, COUNT(tc.Action)
    FROM YourTable t
        LEFT JOIN YourTable tc
            ON t.SessionId = tc.SessionId
                AND tc.Action <> 'LOGIN'
    WHERE t.Action = 'LOGIN'
    GROUP BY t.SessionId;
```

Comment: Can you compare execution times between your and my version of the query? I *guess* the subquery solution is a bit faster here (have no means to measure that right now :/ ).

Comment: @hochl: I have no means of valid comparison either without a good data set. We'll leave that as an exercise for the OP. I will note that the `COUNT(*)-1` in your solution feels like a bit of a hack. What if, hypothetically, a SessionId had more than one LOGIN action?

Answer (score 2):

I did this query using SQlite3:

```
SELECT SessionId, COUNT(*) AS ActionCount
FROM sessions
WHERE SessionId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SessionId
    FROM sessions
    WHERE Action = 'LOGIN')
AND Action <> 'LOGIN'
GROUP BY SessionId;
```

Result:

```
1|3
3|2
```

It does not include sessions where the actions only are of type `LOGIN`, which differs from the requirement.

Comment: You morphed the solution, but now you've lost SessionIds 5 and 6, which the OP has included in his expected results.

Comment: Yeah yeah, going to build a DB to make a performance comparison ... I *think* that left joins *were* much slower, let's see how it plays out. If this one is much faster it's worth considering if you don't need the zero results.

Comment: Make sure it's a *fair* comparison where both queries return the *same* result set. :-)

Comment: :) Ok I'll give my best ... it's still creating the database -- maybe 1 Million records was a little TOO much *fg*

Comment: Ok, on a set with 53k records where 50% have a `LOGIN` field, and the other half not, my original `-1` query produces identical results, but takes 25% less time. Not sure how this translates to other databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT SessionId, COUNT(Action) AS Count
FROM Table
WHERE Action <> "LOGIN"
GROUP BY SessionId
```

The `GROUP BY` will cause it to group the results by a particular column's value.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html